# SQLite - No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0 (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, exception, dialect

I have a SQLite Datatable with string value as id and a BLOB value for a picture.

I want to know if some entry with a specific id exists in the table.

```
Query query = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT logo_id FROM logo WHERE logo_id = ?");
    query.setParameter(1, id);
    int count = query.getResultList().size();
```

But if I execute the query I get this error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1367)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:265)
at at.beko.rainstar2.service.impl.LogoServiceImpl.hasLogoWithId(LogoServiceImpl.java:59)
at at.beko.rainstar2.service.impl.LogoServiceImpl.saveLogo(LogoServiceImpl.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy53.saveLogo(Unknown Source)
at at.beko.rainstar2.ui.controller.OptionController.btnSavePic_click(OptionController.java:204)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:238)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:279)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:759)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:935)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at at.beko.rainstar2.ui.filter.CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.java:25)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)



Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:76)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:99)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:565)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:660)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:564)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:580)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1961)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:331)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1784)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:256)
... 71 more
```

And if I use this code , there are no probs.

```
Query query = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logo WHERE logo_id = ?");
    query.setParameter(1, id);
    Object o = query.getResultList().get(0);
    int count = Integer.valueOf(o.toString());
```

Why I'am getting an error in the other code version, because the select statement must be valid!?

Thanks.

regards matthias

Update:

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="at.beko.rainstar2" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="rainstarDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="rainstar-pu" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="at.beko.rainstar2.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="rainstarDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/rainstar_ds"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think it is a problem in the hibernate.cfg.xml or in the call of Configuration.configure(). Can you post that pls?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate only as provider. In general I'm using JSF,Spring,JPA(Hibernate,Sqlite). So I have no hibernate.cf.xml or Configuration.configure() call. Sorry. Maybe there are Problems with the SQLite Dialect implementation?! Because in the first select version i get no results if there is no id match. In the second select i only work around the problem, because here i get a result (because of the count function). Maybe hibernate does not know how to handle "no results" with the sqlite dialect?! I hope you cann follow what I mean!!? ^^

Comment: If you'd use only hibernate, then in the hibernate.cfg.xml you have to tell which sql dialect to use. I don't use Spring, so I don't know if Spring configures the dialect anywhere else, nevertheless there must be a place where you tell your system which sql dialect to use.

Comment: Oh ok. I have the applicationContext.xml whicht spring needs. In this file I also have the database configuration stuff. Maybe you can take a look at it!? I have added it to my first post!

Comment: I get that error when I have 0 results returned...still looking into how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

`JDBC type: 0` means `Null` in `java.sql.Types`. The `resultSet` must contains null value, but hibernate could not support this datatype for SQLite. So you should set this mapping in your customize `at.beko.rainstar2.dialect.SQLiteDialect`.

```
public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLiteDialect() {
        super();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerHibernateType(Types.NULL, "null");
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in where my SQL query was normalising multiple rows into one column, giving;

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

So I had to wrap the XML result in a converter to convert it to varchar.

e.g. changed from

```
STUFF((select '   ' + RFID as [text()] from InnerTable inner 
       where inner.id = outer.id for XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
as RFIDs
```

to

```
CONVERT(varchar(100), 
STUFF((select '   ' + RFID as [text()] from InnerTable inner 
       where inner.id = outer.id for XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
) as RFIDs
```