# No dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

If I run a query in hibernate like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select 'test' from dual where 1=2").list()
```

I correctly get `size=(0)`.

However when I run a hibernate query like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select null from dual where 1=2").list()
```

I get an error saying `"No dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0"?

How can I fix it so that instead of an error I get results size=(0)?

*** EDIT *** 
I configure the dialect for hibernate in the hibernate.cfg.xml like so:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it's a very late answer, but if someone did have the same issue : 
Problem here is that executing query :

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select null from dual where 1=2").list()
```

A field is not related to any table and always set to null. 
Hibernate rely on resultset metadata to construct answer... and in this case, metadata return an java.sql.SQLType with a value of 0, because database doesn't know the type of the data.

One of the workaround is casting the null value :

```
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select CAST(null as char) from dual where 1=2").list()
```

Comment: this works for me. thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

I was deep into some spaghetti code that was required to support multiple databases and multiple dialects that I did not want to mess with (MySql, Oracle, MS SqlServer).  The code was also executing native sql.  I was able to successfully replace something like:

select null as required_field, foo from bar;

With

select '' as required_field, foo from bar;

This is a hack but it carried the day.

Better solutions seem to be discussed here:

[SQLite - No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0 (Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719117/sqlite-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-0-hibernate)

[Sqlite & Hibernate Ex: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520751/sqlite-hibernate-ex-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-0)

https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: select ' ' instead of select null worked for me. Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Comment: I tried that and still got the same error.  I also tried creating my own Dialect that extended MySQLDialect and adding registerHibernateType(Types.NULL, "null");
registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null"); Neither of those worked though.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try `hibernate.dialect` instead of `dialect`

Comment: Same error, but I sure appreciate you at least taking the time.