# Sqlite & Hibernate Ex: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, jpa

Im using a custom dialect( https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/ ) for connect Sqlite with Hibernate. Because Hibernate doesnt full support Sqlite yet.

If i don't add following lines to `SqliteDialect`, `query.list()` throwing `MappingException`

```
registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
registerHibernateType(Types.NULL, "null");
```

I added `nullable = true` to my Entity @Column.

That currently looking good but if this column have a `null` value and When i called `query.list()`, it throws `NullPointerException`.

How could I resolve this. What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite did not solve the problem. But, I've currently integrated H2 db to my project. Thats looking fine now.