# org.hibernate.MappingException exception in selecting data from view by using hibernate sql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

1.I have use below code for selecting table data. But i have a problem of "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0" when i am trying to get data from the view.I want result in List> . Please help me out.

```
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer());
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

2.Query statement
SELECT cardnumber_parent_id, authorization_status, expiry_date, cardnumber FROM v_authorization_list WHERE charger_id = 'REE001' AND cardnumber = '123456';

3.Stack Trace Exception

```
            Hibernate: SELECT cardnumber_parent_id, authorization_status, expiry_date, cardnumber FROM v_authorization_list WHERE charger_id =
[06 May 2014 12:05:24:163] ERROR PersistanceManager::get:102 - 1011101001: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:370)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1796)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
        at com.gridscape.framework.mediationlayer.adapters.PersistanceManager.get(PersistanceManager.java:76)
        at com.gridscape.ocppserver.services.impl.BasicTransactionServiceImpl.tagAuthorized(BasicTransactionServiceImpl.java:115)
        at com.gridscape.ocppserver.services.impl.BasicTransactionServiceImpl.authorized(BasicTransactionServiceImpl.java:170)
        at com.gridscape.ocppserver.soapserver.services.impl.CentralSystemServiceImpl.authorize(CentralSystemServiceImpl.java:312)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:68)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Are you hardcoding a Hibernate dialect when creating session factory?

Comment: I am using hibernate.cfg.xml that contains 
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

Comment: remove it and try again. Hibernate can autodetect what dialect to use and its more accurate than manually setting it yourself. There are 5 different MySQL dialects that correspond to which version of MySQL you are using

Comment: Did that work? if not then there are other things to try

Comment: No.I have Mysql 5.5.16.

Comment: Can you post the actual query and the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

`No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0` means that you have a null value for some field in some of the rows. You need to see what can be null and maybe you need an explicit cast in the SQL query.

Also see this
[SQLite - No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0 (Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719117/sqlite-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-0-hibernate)

BTW you should post the query and the exception trace.

Comment: I didn't get this problem when using the same code with the table.Table contains null value too.